# Null Pointer Exception in String Comparison

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

```
while(true)
        {
            String input = "";
            try {
                input = in.readLine();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e1 + "Exception occured when reading user input");
            }
            // Sleep
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(USER_THROTTLE);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(toString()+" has input interrupted.");
            }

            if(input .equals("w")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("a")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("s")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("d")){action_event(input);}

            if(input .equals("eat")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("drink")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("place")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("swim")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("command_kill")){action_event(input);}
            if(input .equals("help")){action_event(input);}
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Platypus_User$Inport.run(Platypus_User.java:64)
```

This is being ran in Eclipse on Mac OSX.
A Null Pointer Exception occurs following the second catch block where the string is compared to "w" then if it is "w" the action_event method is called.

I have no clue why this would be happening. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Post the full stracktrace. Always post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Also, some advice: when you need to write something like this: if(input .equals("w")), it might be better to write it as: if ("w".equals(input)) since it will never be possible for this version to throw a NPE.

Comment: @Stultuske better use `Set#contains()` though such code repetitions make code look dirty

Answer (score 3):

I guess `in` is a `BufferedReader`. `readLine` will return null if End Of The Stream is reached.

See [BufferedReader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: Yes "in" is a Buffered Reader. How should I read user input then ?

Comment: You should just check if input == null, and skip the checks

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader.readLine() can return null, so check for null on input.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid repetitions in code. You can collect all allowed inputs in one `Set` and then just check if it contains particular value--thus making code look much more readable, short and clean.

Second, you need to perform null check, because `in.read()` can return null as mentioned in other answers. `null` input could also be used for termination of `while` loop.

So I would rewrite your code as following:

```
Set<String> allowedInputs 
    = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("w", "a", "s", "d", "eat")); // <- add remaining allowed inputs here

String input = "";

while (input != null) {    
    try {
        input = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1 + "Exception occured when reading user input");
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(USER_THROTTLE);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(toString() + " has input interrupted.");
    }
    if (input != null && allowedInputs.contains(input)) { // <- check if input is allowed
         action_event(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never invoke methods on objects which are not initialized. input may hold a null value. So before comparing you must make sure that object is not null.
Best approach to handle such situations would be by comparing a constant value with "input" instead of comparing input with a constant value.
eg "w".equals(input)